# How would I prevent JQuery from selecting more than 1 level of children dom elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I only select Item A and Item B pragmatically while excluding the sub item?

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <p>Item A</p>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <p>Sub Item A</p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Item B</li>        
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Item B has no unique way of addressing it (no class or id to separate it from other LI tags at that level) and it's not in a `<p>` tag either.  Are you sure this is the HTML you want to ask about?

Comment: Pragmatically? Do you mean programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will select any first level li's that have only text and no children and any children of a li that isnt a ul. Given this is not a good way to do it. You should really put classes on your stuff to start with. But if that's not an option this will get you there.

```
$($('#nav').children()).children().each(function(){
    if($(this).text() !== "" && $(this).children().length === 0 ){
       $(this).addClass("IwantThisElement");       
    }
});

$($($('#nav') .children()) .children()) .children(':not(ul)').each(function(){
    if($(this).text() !== ""){
       $(this).addClass("IwantThisElement");       
    }
});


$('.IwantThisElement').text('Assuming Control');
```

Answer (score 2):

Well after a quick test run - this is my contribution to this issue

```
$("#nav p:first, #nav > ul > li:eq(1)");
```

You specified that you wanted only those two items and no sub items so this is what jQuery will capture :

```
[<p>​Item A​</p>​, <li>​Item B​</li>​]
```

You can easily separate `selectors` by placing a comma between them.

---

Now that you have seen my solution I would strongly suggest that you take [Xenon06's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9810558/558021)...
Giving your markup classes really helps you to keep track of them.  Especially with jQuery.  The `class` attribute while IMO mostly used for styling is a perfectly valid selector to use <s>and abuse</s> in your jQuery code.  That is of course if you actually have access to that HTML.  If you don't kindly ignore my last paragraph :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your structure was more consistent, you could use direct children selectors, ie:

```
$("#nav ul li > p")
```

However your Item B is not in a paragraph. Without defining more what you want, you'll need to put classes on the items you want and do

```
$("#nav .yourclass")
```

Comment: that probably should be `"#nav > ul > li > p"`